# Are there any programs to draw and test state machines, turing machines, etc?

Tags: computer-science, state-machine, finite-automata

When I go back to school after Thanksgiving, I'll be taking a course in CS Theory covering topics such as deterministic and nondeterministic finite state machines, turing machines, pushdown automata and a few other things. However, I haven't found a good application that can produce a visual representation of them as well as testing how they work (pass/fail, etc). The best that I've found so far is [jFlap](http://www.jflap.org/), and I'm finding it rather awkward.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I used a java finite state machine program when I was in college, but I can't remember what it was called.  I'm trying to find it for you.

Comment: I know it's not a duplicate, but rather a direct result of that question. That is why I made the smiley.

Comment: Aaron Smith: It's probably jFlap. It is Java, and very meh. But if that's what you come up with, post it as an answer.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with JFLAP? It was specifically designed as a didactic instrument: you can do conversion algorithms or matchings step-by-step, etc. (OK, the online help is in the form of Haiku poems, which is a little weird.) But it is a great tool.

Comment: I just find jFlap awkward to use. I usually fumble around for a little while before getting the job done. I don't feel it's intuitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was [JFlap](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jflap/) that I used in college.  I didn't find it that awkward to use, but it looks like it may have changed since then.  Sorry I don't have a better answer for you than that.

Comment: Well, jFlap (as awkward as I find it) might be the best thing out there and if I want an app, I'll have to just learn how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine used Latex to draw them. I always preferred pencil and paper.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in a class like this right now. I've found paper and pencil to be sufficient. I can't say for sure, but I don't think you'll be required to draw automata that are too complicated to understand on one sheet of paper.

Comment: That's true, but I've got messy writing style, which makes it very difficult to write for turning in and testing. Although I manage on tests, relying on that for everything would be a pain. It is something that I am considering, however.

Comment: Never underestimate the complexity of a real-world state diagram!  We've got one here that _does_ need 8px font on an A3 sheet.  (Though it should be modulized a bit...)

Answer (score 1):

I drew them in UML and submitted StarUML jpeg exports for a while.

Then I wrote a PHP script to convert them to DOT format and used Graphviz to get nice-looking machines.

Comment: I forgot about DOT and Graphviz. That's an option I should look into, but it doesn't allow for testing the machines - I would have to do that by hand.

Comment: Yes. Since it was sufficient for me to test by hand, I never got around to modifying the script to test the machine as well. Graphviz does produce pretty-looking pictures, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Simulink Stateflow.

Massive overkill, of course.

Answer (score 0):

[IAR visualSTATE](http://www.iar.com/website1/1.0.1.0/371/1/index.php) might be of interest.

Comment: That looks cool, but it doesn't appear to support all the different types of automata clearly, and it costs money. I think some people might be interested in this, but it doesn't look like it's good for me.